# Android generalized function for state flow in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using `StateFlow` in my app and in my `Fragment` I use this to -

```
private var job: Job? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        job = lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            viewModel.getData().collect {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        job?.cancel()
        super.onPause()
    }
```

As you see I cancel the job in `onPause`. How could I use a generalized function so that I can avoid doing the `job?.cancel` in every fragment.

I prefer not to use a `BaseFragment`

Comment: you can create abstract class with job?.cancel() in onPause and extend it

Comment: @AlexRmcf Can you pls provide me an example

Comment: Any particular reason for not to use a base fragment?

Comment: Over a period of time as the app grows, the base classes get misused no matter what

Comment: Do you plan on collecting the flow again when the fragment is resumed? I cant see a usecase for only collecting until the first pause

Comment: @AdrianK No I dont plan on collecting the flow again when the fragment is resumed. The documentation https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow says if the job is not cancelled it could waste resources when the UI is not in the foreground state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to utilize the fragments lifecycle to automatically cancel the job when it is paused.

```
fun CoroutineScope.launchUntilPaused(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit){
    val job = launch(block = block)
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            job.cancel()
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}

//Usage
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launchUntilPaused(this){
            someFlow.collect{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have many of these jobs per fragment, I would advice to use a custom `CoroutineScope` instead, to avoid having many lifecycle observers active.

```
class CancelOnPauseScope(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner): CoroutineScope by MainScope(){
    init{
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver{
            override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                cancel()
                lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
            }
        })
    }
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val scope = CancelOnPauseScope(this)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        scope.launch{
            someFlow.collect{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the first implementation will work incorrectly. You are subscribing to collect in onViewCreated() but stop listening in onPause(). It can produce a situation, when, for example, the user block a device and then unblock, so your subscription will be lost.
It is probably better to subcribe in onStart() and cancel in onStop, or even onResume() and onPause().

Comment: @AndriiAfanasenko You are absolutely correct, thats how it works. However, the question was how to achieve this exact behavior

Comment: Hi, this solution will work but, when you come back with onBackPressed() from the other page you went to with intent, the flow is not listened to because we canceled the current listening. How can we solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

a new way:

```
   // Start a coroutine in the lifecycle scope
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        // repeatOnLifecycle launches the block in a new coroutine every time the
        // lifecycle is in the STARTED state (or above) and cancels it when it's STOPPED.
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AnyOfYourFragments extends AbsractFragment{

   //you do here what you want to do
   
}
```

And in your AbstractFragment:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment{
private var job: Job? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        job = lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            viewModel.getData().collect {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        job?.cancel()
        super.onPause()
    }
}
```

I don't know kotlin, so my code is kind of mix with java but i'm sure you got the idea